# Cakephp - how to encrypt and then decrypt data that is being stored and retrieved from the database

Tags: php, security, cakephp, encryption, md5

Err.... like the question says.

How do I go about encrypting and then decrypting data that is being stored and retrieved from the database.

By the way it's not just for storing a password which has been md5ed, I need to retrieve the data too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this in the various before methods in my models, or better still create a before method in my app controller which encrypted and decrypted data.

```
afterFind(); //decrypt
beforeSave(); //encrypt
```

Would be the methods that I would choose.

PS, I should mention Behaviours here also really, as that's the ideal 'Cake way' to achieve this kind of thing, http://book.cakephp.org/view/595/Creating-Behaviors

Comment: Just to clarify, while afterFind/beforeSave are the correct approach, you only really need to bundle the code in a behavior if you plan on reusing this functionality in more than one model.

Answer (score 1):

there are several articles in cakephp to store and retrieve your table fields in encrypt/decrypt values automatically or manually

take a look at

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/xemle/2008/08/26/cipher-behavior

and

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/utoxin/2009/08/01/cryptable-behavior

with these way you can customize what field(s) you want to encrypt the data and also how to decrypt. You will need MCRYPT module in your php